# Issue validating Username and Password when registering

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

What I am trying to do is get values from registration form from angular project and register those details into Sql Server. However, I am having an issue validating the password and I am not sure if it is validating user details correctly. I am getting an unhandled exception error, where value cannot be null, even though I did input the password. I tried removing `model.Password` from `var manager`, but validation failed. I would like to know how to validate the user details properly.

> warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager[13]
>         User cbb07b96-0058-4367-a8e1-6c99aaf63609 validation failed: InvalidUserName.

Powershell details:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS http://localhost:5000/api/User/Register
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[4]
      CORS policy execution successful.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 105.3865ms 204
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:5000/api/User/Register application/json 90
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[4]
      CORS policy execution successful.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Route matched with {action = "Register", controller = "Account"}. Executing action UserWebAPI.Controllers.AccountController.Register (UserWebAPI)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method UserWebAPI.Controllers.AccountController.Register (UserWebAPI) with arguments (UserWebAPI.Models.AccountModel) - Validation state: Valid
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action UserWebAPI.Controllers.AccountController.Register (UserWebAPI) in 266.4197ms
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: password
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.CreateAsync(TUser user, String password)
   at UserWebAPI.Controllers.AccountController.Register(AccountModel model) in C:\Users\cashamerica12345\Documents\UserWebAPI\UserWebAPI\UserWebAPI\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 39
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 783.9354ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[32]
      Connection id "0HLOK8BLGB4T6", Request id "0HLOK8BLGB4T6:00000002": the application completed without reading the entire request body.
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using UserWebAPI.Models;
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace UserWebAPI.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

        public AccountController (IConfiguration config, 
            IMapper mapper,
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _mapper = mapper;
            _config = config;
        }

        [Route("api/User/Register", Name = "GetUser") ]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(AccountModel model) //add async Task<Result>
        {
            //var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new DataContext());
            var userStore = _mapper.Map<ApplicationUser>(model);
            //var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
            var manager = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userStore, model.Password); 
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };
            //var user = _mapper.Map<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
            user.FirstName = model.FirstName;
            user.LastName = model.LastName;

            if (manager.Succeeded)
            {
                //IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, model.Password);
                return CreatedAtRoute("GetUser", new { id = userStore.Id }, user);
            }
            return BadRequest(manager.Errors);
        }    
    }
}
```

**sign-up.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <form class="col s12 white" #UserRegistrationForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(UserRegistrationForm)" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="sm-jumbotron center-align">
              <h2>User Registration</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
            <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s6">          
            <input type="text" name="FirstName" #FirstName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.FirstName">
              <label>First Name</label>
            </div>
              <div class="input-field col s6">
                  <input type="text" name="LastName" #FirstName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.LastName">
                    <label>Last Name</label>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <input type="text" class="validate" name="UserName" #UserName="ngModel" [ngModel]="user.UserName" required>
                    <label data-error="Required Field">Username</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input type="password" class="validate" name="Password" #Password="ngModel" [ngModel]="user.Password" required minlength="6">
                <label [attr.data-error] = "Password.errors != null?(password.errors.required? 'Required Field' : 'Minimum 6 characters'):''"> 
                  Password</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <input type="text" name="Email" #Email="ngModel" [ngModel]="user.Email" [pattern]="emailPattern">
                    <label data-error="Invalid email">Email</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <button class="btn-large btn-submit" [disabled]="!userRegisterFrom.valid" type="submit">Submit</button>
                  </div>
                </div>


                </form>
              </div>
```

**IdentityModel.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UserWebAPI.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }


    }

    public class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> //DataContext instead of ApplicationDbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            //AspNetUsers -> User
            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .ToTable("User");
            //AspNetRoles -> Role
            builder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
                .ToTable("Role");
            //AspNetRoles -> UserRole
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>()
                .ToTable("UserRole");
            //AspNetUserClaims -> UserClaim
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>()
                .ToTable("UserClaim");
            //AspNetUserLogins -> UserLogin
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>()
                .ToTable("UserLogin");
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try to debug your code and check whether `model.Password` has value, as the error indicates, the `model.Password` is null. Share us the network tab and request when you click submit button.

Comment: in network tab, the password property did not go through. I shared pic.

Comment: Try to change `password` to `Password` in form.

Comment: I think I tried that already, but I will try again.

Comment: I tried putting all password to Password and it still did not work, still the same.

Comment: If you would like to look at my project, I will share link here: https://github.com/alextech1/UserWebAPI

Comment: Make sure restart your client SPA and start a new private web browser to test your project. I download your project and make a test, it works correctly.

Comment: Ok, so I figured out that I did not rebuild it correctly, I needed the [FromBody] tag and it is why it was not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need the `[FromBody]` attribute in your controller method.

Instead of this...

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(AccountModel model)
```

Try this...

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register([FromBody] AccountModel model)
```

Comment: Have you tried calling the API directly (with something like Postman) to see if that works? you may have two different issues. Also, try removing validation from the password field and/or make it a plain text field (just to test)

Comment: Actually, I might have not rebuild it correctly, I tried again and this is why it was not working.